# Unable to create a search filter for roles, which displays all the users with the selected role - Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a `belongsToMany` eloquent relationship between `App/Models/User` and `App/Models/Role`. The relationship between the user and the role is stored in `role_user` pivot table. I am trying to create an advanced search filter, which will display me the list of users under the specific role criteria.

I have already done this for email criteria, i.e. the concerned user will be displayed, if the email of the registered user matches the input. This was easy to achieve as the email column exists in the users table itself.

How can I achieve the same for the role criteria, which will relate to the user through a pivot table, and will display the end number of users with the selected role.

[image]

**App/Models/User**

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

**App/Models/Role**

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

**App/Http/Livewire/UserController**

```
public $filters = [
    'email' => null,
    'role' => ''
];

public function render() {
    $users = User::query() 
        -> when($this -> filters['email'], fn($query, $email) => $query -> where('email', $email))
        -> when($this -> filters['role'], fn($query, $role) => $query -> with('roles') -> where('id', $role))
        -> search('name', $this -> search)
        -> paginate(5);
    $roles = Role::all();
    return view('livewire.user-controller', ['users' => $users, 'roles' => $roles]);
}
```

**resources/views/livewire/user-controller**

```
<!-- Advanced Search -->
<div>
    @if ($showFilters)
    <div>
        <div>
            <x-input.group inline for="filter-email" label="Email">
                <x-input.text wire:model.lazy="filters.email" id="filter-email" placeholder="Enter Email" />
            </x-input.group>
        </div>
        <div>
            <x-input.group inline for="filter-role" label="Role">
                <x-input.select wire:model.lazy="filters.role" id="filter-role" placeholder="Select Role">
                    @foreach($roles as $role)
                    <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </x-input.select>
            </x-input.group>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>

<!-- Users Table -->
<x-table>
    <x-slot name="head">
        <x-table.heading>
            <x-input.checkbox />
        </x-table.heading>
        <x-table.heading>ID</x-table.heading>
        <x-table.heading>Name</x-table.heading>
        <x-table.heading>Email</x-table.heading>
        <x-table.heading>Role</x-table.heading>
    </x-slot>

    <x-slot name="body">
        @foreach($users as $key => $user)
        <x-table.row wire:loading.class.delay="opacity-50">
            <x-table.cell wire:key="row-{{ $user->id }}">
                <x-input.checkbox wire:model="selected" value="{{ $user->id }}" />
            </x-table.cell>
            <x-table.cell>{{ $users->firstitem() + $key }}</x-table.cell>
            <x-table.cell>{{ $user->name }}</x-table.cell>
            <x-table.cell>{{ $user->email }}</x-table.cell>
            <x-table.cell>
                @foreach($user->roles as $role)
                {{ $role->name }}
                @endforeach
            </x-table.cell>
        </x-table.row>
        @endforeach
    </x-slot>
</x-table>
```

Comment: You can use `whereHas` with a callback function to filter query results based on the relationship. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @miken32 Please can you be more descriptive, can you assist me with the code, as I am stuck at the same place since 4 days now, I know it might be silly, but I'm very much new to Laravel. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve all users who have a role with an id of 5

```php
//Say this role id (5) is received as a result of user selecting a role from select
$roleId = 5; 

$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) use($roleId) {
    return $query->where('id', $roleId);
});
```

> Thanks for the answer, can you help me by getting it to work in the query format. User::query()->when($this -> filters['role'], fn($query, $role) => $query -> with('roles') ->where('id', $role)) as I need to bind it along with the state of the function to detect the request when($this -> filters['role']. Thank you for your time.

```php
User::query()
  ->when(
    $this->filters['role'], 
    fn($query, $role) => $query->whereHas(
        'roles', 
        fn($query) => $query->where('id', $role)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you help me by getting it to work in the query format. `User::query()->when($this -> filters['role'], fn($query, $role) => $query -> with('roles') ->where('id', $role))` as I need to bind it along with the state of the function to detect the request `when($this -> filters['role']`. Thank you for your time.

Comment: As I tried, I'm getting errors, as I am not building and relating the relationship in the query properly.

Comment: @ToxifiedHashkey Have updated the answer, pls check and let me know it this works for you